# UFT/QTP CreateObject Syntax error

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I try to create object in UFT:

```
Dim xlApp 
Dim xlBook 
Dim xlSheet 
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\1.xls")
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
```

Creating fails with Syntax error in

```
The test run cannot continue due to a syntax error.
Syntax error
Line (242): Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Does anybody know how to repair it?
Thanks for the help

Comment: You probably have something in the 239 lines not shown that creates this error somehow...?

Comment: Also think about assigning the `CreateObject` result to `xlApp`, but referencing `xlObj` in the next line...same with `xlBook` vs. `xlWBObj`...;) That means: Run your code, I mean: exactly the code snippet you post -- before you post it.

Comment: change reference but it not help

Comment: The code you posed doesn't seem to be using any UFT specific code. Try putting it in a `.vbs` file to see if it's a problem with your vbscript.

Comment: The code as shown now should work, in "pure" VBS and in QTP. What about the 239 lines not shown? It could be a missing end if, or whatever. Do you really get a syntax error if you copy the code from the question into a fresh QTP test? If so, disassociate all libraries from the test, and re-run. Still an error? Would be very strange.

Comment: in fresh QTP test it works! may be problem that i use 
Class myClass
..my code.. End Class

Comment: Yeah...that *might* contribute to the problem lolz ;) see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your comment, you are using somthing like:

```
Class MyClass
    Dim xlApp 
    Dim xlBook 
    Dim xlSheet 

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\1.xls")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
End Class
```

Then, you get a syntax error in the xlApp assignment.

And right so, **because the assignment is invalid in that scope (which is no callable scope at all)**.

First of all, set `option explicit on`.

Then, make sure you define all instance variables with `Dim`.

Also, create a constructor, or as in the following sample, a callable `Sub`, which initializes the instance variables, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Class MyClass
    Dim xlApp 
    Dim xlBook 
    Dim xlSheet 
    Public Function SetParam ()
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\1.xls")
        Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    End Function
End Class
```

This would not generate a syntax error, and might be closer to what you intended.

This is because inside a `Class`...`End Class` construct, you cannot have anything else but definitions. No statements. And assignments are statements. (Initialization using "`=`" in a variable definition is not supported by VBScript.)